# Intellij Idea not deploying artifacts in JBoss Eap 7.0.4 deployment

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, jboss-eap-7

we have a multi-modules gradle project. I have imported that project as gradle project in IntelliJ 2017 and Configure JBoss eap server. Server started but artefact doesn't deploy. Gradle task creating artefacts and I have added these to deployment.

Comment: Any errors/warning in output when JBoss is starting and when deploying the artifact?

Comment: No, but I have to do clean and full gradle build then It works

Comment: If I change one class, if I exploded artifact It, should automatically take changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring-boot application we have to configure devtools which basically reload classes.  Intellij sever configuration doesn't work with spring-boot unless devtool configured.